# Should I use "didn't it" or "hadn't it" in the following sentence?

Tags: auxiliary-verbs, tag-questions

> The story had a happy ending, didn't/hadn't it?

I'm confused because Google returns both results:

> But it had a happy ending, didn't it? [Source](https://www.google.com.tw/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCMQFjABahUKEwiz5OH_strIAhXKoZQKHVx4Bfw&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.fanfiction.net%2Fs%2F10997802%2F2%2F50-shades-of-Emison&usg=AFQjCNHjvgzb7FmepFHvHNKsNj9R6u3CFQ&sig2=iHSnlVwp8gdVwXlKr55_Cw).
>
> That had been quite a happy ending, hadn't it? [Source](https://www.google.com.tw/search?biw=1280&bih=938&q=%22%20a%20happy%20ending%20hadn%27t%20it%22&oq=%22%20a%20happy%20ending%20hadn%27t%20it%22&gs_l=serp.3...94256.94644.0.94764.6.4.0.0.0.0.181.181.0j1.1.0....0...1c.1.64.serp..6.0.0.YZWpS4SMmKs).

What's the correct option and why?

Comment: Google gave 4,780 results for "didn't" and *only* 4 result for "hadn't it."

Comment: Use like for like!  _"The story had a happy ending, hadn't it?"_   _"The story did have a happy ending, didn't it?"_   _"The story does have a happy ending, doesn't it?"_   _"The story has a happy ending, hasn't it?"_ etc etc.

Answer (score 3):

The usual approach to forming the confirmation interrogative after a statement is to repeat the subject (possibly substituted with a *pronoun*) and use the auxiliary verb "do" or "be" ***in the same tense***.  Essentially you ask a short question (without all the substance) *an answer to which* would be *the original statement*.

> **We are** having a great party, ***aren't we***? (*present continuous*)
>   **Children grew** up quickly, ***didn't they***?  (*past indefinite*)
>   **Mark has got** a lot on his plate, ***hasn't he***? (*present perfect*)
>   **The story will** be interesting, ***won't it***? =  (*future indefinite*)
>   **There's been** several attempts to explain it, ***hasn't there***?  (*present perfect*)
>   ...***and so on***

Sometimes people use the "*isn't it*" confirmation to statements that involve people as subjects and actions as verbs, like

> Victor just muddies the waters, isn't it?

but that is grammatically incorrect.  The subject of the question part needs to represent the subject of the statement and the verb needs to represent the state or the action (or be the same modal or auxilirary):

> **Peter, John and Paul should** study for the exams, ***shouldn't they***?
>   **Scientists must** account for those factors, ***mustn't they***?

---

There were times when "have" (and some other verbs) could be used to begin a question in present or past indefinite tense like "do" or "be" nowadays.  You can still see in the literature:

> **Have** you a light?
>   **Has** he any idea what's going to happen?

which suggests that after a statement with "have" as the main verb we could see a confirmation question start not with "do" but with "have" in the appropriate tense, but it's not idiomatic now.

With that in mind, your confirmation questions should be

> The story **had** a happy ending, ***didn't it***?  ("had" = *past indefinite*, "it" = "story")